# Magento how to email from view.phtml file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to display an email form in view.phtml file and send mail when send button clicked. Is it possible to send an email from view.phtml file(catalog/product/view.phtml). Please help.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/ This'll probably help you